# How can I force PDFsharp to embed a subset of a font only?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc, font-embedding

I am able to sucessfully create PDF files using PDFsharp and MigraDoc.
Two private fonts (OTF format) are used for the creation of a single page PDF. The created PDF contains both fonts fully embedded.
Unfortunatly each font contains Chinese letters too and therefor measures about 4 MB in size each, resulting in a PDF file size about 9 MB (containing one page with a bit of text only!). :shock:

Is it possible to use a subset of those fonts to save valuable space.
The thing is I need to create a few thousand PDF files and therefor file size is crucial.

**Is there a special setting i can use?**
**Can anyone point me into the right direction?**

**Update**:
I used fontforge to extract the embedded font subgroub and found out that the fonts derived from the pdf match the full font files exactly.
So no font subsetting is indeed used at all. :(

Taking a look into the PDFsharp sources I found the function

```
public OpenTypeFontface CreateFontSubSet(Dictionary<int, object> glyphs, bool cidFont)
```

which is commented as follows: *Creates a new font image that is a subset of this font image containing only the specified glyphs.*
Which is exactly what I want to be used here.

The thing I do not understand here is why this function seems not to get used when creating my PDF.
**What criteria needs to be met in order to make it work?**

Comment: I know this is an old question: Which fonts are you using and are the fonts available for download? We would like to see how it is possible to create subsets.

Comment: The fonts used are fonts that are unfortunatly not available for download because of copyright issues. Even creating a subset of a copyrighted font might break copyright permissions. Subsets of a font can be created using the open source tool Fontforge or (applied to a pdf) ghostscript.

Comment: If we cannot obtain the fonts, if we do not even know the name and the publisher of the fonts, then we cannot adjust PDFsharp to create subsets. I did not ask you to infringe copyrights, I just asked for information and - in the best case - a legal download link.
Is there a suitable Noto font for Chinese?

Comment: try that one: https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+SC

Answer (score 2):

Just found a solution to my problem that requires no extensive fiddling with additional pdf frameworks. I am able to create font subsets using ghostscript (commandline).

In fact ghostscript takes the (pdfsharp-) generated file and rewrites it (while optimizing the fonts). Here the commandline solution:

```
gswin64 -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dCompressFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=optimized.pdf -c ".setpdfwrite <</NeverEmbed [ ]>> setdistillerparams" -f my_pdfsharp.pdf
```

My file size of about 9 MB is now down to 51 KB. Yihaa!!!

Answer (score 1):

Some fonts have a "loca table", some do not. The loca table stores the offsets to the locations of the glyphs in the font.

`CreateFontSubSet` is and can only be called for fonts with a loca table that provides the information needed to create subsets.